# Multiple accounts paypal with one IPN listener

Tags: listener, paypal-ipn, merchant-account

I'm the administrator of a site that allows anyone with a valid paypal account to sell online.
The problem is that the response of the ipn listener is INVALID because in the paypal's account sellers isn't set the url of my listener.
How can I do to sell more merchants on my site?
Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the adaptive payments , you( as an API caller) can always pass the IPN url in your API call's using the "ipnNotificationUrl" variable .This way you can receive all transaction related details on the specified IPN url irrespective of the IPN url set in the seller's account .

Comment: I use the immediate payment and fields in the post method are: 
field name "cmd" value "_xclick" 
name field "notify_url" value "url of my listeners" 
and other standard fields. 
So it should already work for you?

Comment: @GiordanoFlorian Have you fixed this issue, im facing the same problem and im also using the immediat payment.